# Best practice for rendering data after posting a form in mvc 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Example:
I have a 'Contact Us' view and controller.

My view renders a contact us form as well as the rest of the page containing postal, telephone and email information.

When the form is submitted I want to render the same data, just minus the contact us form and display a 'message sent' instead.

I have a 'Send' method on the controller and can create a 'Send' view with all the data from the contact us view, minus the contact us form and with the 'message sent' string.  But obviously having the code now duplicated in two places is far from ideal.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Ajax.BeginForm instead of using BeginForm. The reason is you don't need to create another action, Ajax.BeginForm will update the display partial view for you.

Below is an example:

**Action**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    return View(new Contact());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(Contact contact)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //
    }
    return PartialView("_messagePartialView", contact);
}
```

**View**

```
  @model  Demo.Models.Contact

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

    <div id="result">        
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email)

            <input type="submit" value="OK" />
        }    
    </div>
```

**Partial View: _messagePartialView**

```
  @model  Demo.Models.Contact

    <h1>
        @Model.Email
    </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have a Contact Model that you use to get the data from user.

And I assume you have the Send Method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send(Contact contact){
  // process your model. ie : send email etc.

  TempData["contactData"] = contact;

  return RedirectToAction("Sent");
}

public Actionresult Sent(){

  return View();
}
```

In sent view you can use `TempData` and access `Contact` model properties.